# Is there any tools for turning the JS speed?

Tags: javascript, performance

I would like to test which lines of js use the most resource, apart from printing the ts one by one.... Is there any tools for analysis the js performance? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the essential tool for Firefox:

http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out the integrated development tools in Google Chrome, which are pretty good too.
Since you seem interested in performance, you can also have a look at [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) and [PageSpeed](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/speed/page-speed/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebug or chrome developer tools to profile your javascript.

Also, give http://jsperf.com/ a try.